# Add New Row and Copy Data To That Row

Tags: vba, excel, row, addition

I am looking for help creating a new row in VBA.  Columns A:C are general items, Columns D:F are VBA formulas driven values in Columns A:C. (Basically If Then statements)

Our system, for analysis, requires a single line item for each criteria met.  Row 1 meets two criteria; "Inq" & "High". So I need to insert a new row below, copy the data from row 1 A:C, and in column D enter "High".  That way there is a single row of data for "Inq" and "High".

The process would be repeated for every row, excluding the newly added ones. Sorry, this may be a little tricky, but I will help out anyway I can.  I am new to Stackoverflow so I couldn't post an image of my table.

---- Below is an update ----

The code below worked great for Column 19. It inserted the row, inserted the values in the new row, and place "Lead" in the last column.

```
Sub AddRow()

Dim RowIndex As Long
Dim Delta As Long

RowIndex = 2

Do While Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value <> ""
Delta = 0
        If Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 19).Value = "Lead" Then
        ' Inserts new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        ' Takes cells value from row above and enters value in new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 1), Cells(RowIndex + 1, 17)).Value = Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex, 1), Cells(RowIndex, 17)).Value
        ' Puts rating value in last column
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 18), Cells(RowIndex + 1, 18)).Value = "Lead"
        Delta = Delta + 1
        End If
    RowIndex = RowIndex + Delta + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Since I have multiple potential values in the RowIndex, I assumed I could just copy the first If Statement, modify it for the next column and everything will work (see code below).  When I ran it, it inserted two rows, only one row copied down, the other blank.

The problem seems to be if there are multiple values per RowIndex.  I will have the potential for multiple values per RowIndex, in which I would like to create a separate row for each.  See example below the code.

Here is my code that I have been working with
    Sub AddRow()

```
Dim RowIndex As Long
Dim Delta As Long

RowIndex = 2

Do While Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value <> ""
Delta = 0
        If Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 19).Value = "Lead" Then
        ' Inserts new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        ' Takes cells value from row above and enters value in new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 1), Cells(RowIndex + 1, 17)).Value = Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex, 1), Cells(RowIndex, 17)).Value
        ' Puts rating value in last column
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 18), Cells(RowIndex + 1, 18)).Value = "Lead"
        Delta = Delta + 1
    End If
        If Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 20).Value = "HP" Then
        ' Inserts new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        ' Takes cells value from row above and enters value in new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 1), Cells(RowIndex + 1, 17)).Value = Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex, 1), Cells(RowIndex, 17)).Value
        ' Puts rating value in last column
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 18), Cells(RowIndex + 1, 18)).Value = "HP"
        Delta = Delta + 1
     End If
    RowIndex = RowIndex + Delta + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Example Values - Below is not code, and not used in the marcro, example only

```
Example: (RowIndex) A1-A17   Column 19 = "Lead", Column 20 = "HP", Column 21 = "QL"
Output:  (RowIndex) A1-A17   Column 18 = "Lead"
         (RowIndex) A1-A17   Column 18 = "HP"
         (RowIndex) A1-A17   Column 18 = "QL"
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and editing the code produced? Typically questions asking for code which don't show at least some existing code get closed pretty quickly here.

Comment: `The problem looks to be if the RowIndex has multiple values; for instance "Lead" in Column 19, and "HP" in Column 20 of the same row. ` in that instance how many rows would you want to be added? 1 or 2?

Comment: @Sam Ward You are correct in that "Lead" and "HP" will be in the same row. In this case I would like to create two copies of the RowIndex (Columns 1-17), one for "Lead" and one for "HP". As an side, there is the potential for 6-8 values per RowIndex, in which I would like to create a new row for each.  My code above is obviously only for two values, but I trimmed it for clarity.

Comment: @bjk I posted you some code, that you should be able to adapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that may help you get on the right track.

This code currently looks for `foo` in column C of sheet 1 and `bar` in column D and inserts a copy of the row underneath. It will insert 2 rows if both bar and foo exist in a row.

```
Sub InsertRow()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


On Error GoTo err

'loop through the rows from the bottom of the sheet
For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

'column C
    If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "foo" Then

        ws.Rows(i).Copy
        ws.Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    End If

    'Column D
    If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "bar" Then

        ws.Rows(i).Copy
        ws.Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Exit Sub

err:


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "An error occured"

End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks to copy down the entire row.  I am only looking to copy down columns 1-18 from the row above.  I also have updated my code in my original post which may be helpful.

Comment: I was able to modify the code you provided. I am running it through 20K+ rows, and I keep getting a "run time error - disconnect from the client".  Any thoughts?  Is it to much data?  I tested the same code, on a smaller row count, and it worked great.

Comment: @bjk I made some changes... This may help.. Note the `Application.calculation` and the movement of the `Application.CutCopyMode` to inside the loop.

Comment: That did it!  It ran through all 20K+ rows.  Could you explain what you did and why it helped?

Comment: @bjk I googled it and someone had a similar problem. They cleared the clipboard more often with `Application.CutCopyMode = False`.. `Screenupdating` and `Calculation` changes are good for speeding macros up. Just remember to turn them back on at the end of the code or if you hit an error. If you found my answer useful will you accept it please.

Comment: Yes, I will accept the answer. You have been very helpful. Sorry to bother, but I had one more quick question. I am new to VBA, and something is still bothering me. How is your code so different than the one Michel provided. To me is looks fairly similar (before your final changes).  Both use variables, both loop, both use if then statements....

Comment: The other example was based on your original code and used a `Do While` loop, whereas my example uses a `For` Loop

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:  Based on your code in your question:

It add the `Delta` I forgot to put when you copy the line from RowIndex.

```
Dim RowIndex As Long
Dim Delta As Long

RowIndex = 2

Do While Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value <> ""
    Delta = 0
    If Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 19).Value = "Lead" Then
        ' Inserts new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        ' Takes cells value from row above and enters value in new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1), Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 17)).Value = Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex, 1), Cells(RowIndex, 17)).Value
        ' Puts rating value in last column
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 18), Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 18)).Value = "Lead"
        Delta = Delta + 1
    End If

    If Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex, 20).Value = "HP" Then
        ' Inserts new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
        ' Takes cells value from row above and enters value in new row
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 1), Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 17)).Value = Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex, 1), Cells(RowIndex, 17)).Value
        ' Puts rating value in last column
        Sheets("WeeklyReport").Range(Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 18), Cells(RowIndex + Delta + 1, 18)).Value = "HP"
        Delta = Delta + 1
    End If

    RowIndex = RowIndex + Delta + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

---

Here is some code I would suggest as a solution.  I didn't test it because I do not have a set of data to test with nor have the time to set somehting up.  I would say that the general principal is good.

Replace `<enter your test value here>` and `<What you need for this test>` in the code below as they are place holder for the actual value you need.

This code stop when it reaches a empty value in column A.

```
Dim RowIndex as long
Dim Delta as long

RowIndex=1

Do While sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex,1).Value <> ""
    Delta=0
    ' For the value in column D
    if sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex,4).Value=<enter your test value here> then
        'insert row
        sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex+Delta+1,1).entirerow.insert

        'Put the value for your result
        sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndexDelta+1,1).value=<What you need for this test>

        Delta=Delta+1
    end if

    ' For the value in column E
    if sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex,5).Value=<enter your test value here> then
        'insert row
        sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex+Delta+1,1).entirerow.insert

        'Put the value for your result
        sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndexDelta+1,1).value=<What you need for this test>

        Delta=Delta+1
    end if

    ' For the value in column F        
    if sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex,6).Value=<enter your test value here> then
        'insert row
        sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndex+Delta+1,1).entirerow.insert

        'Put the value for your result
        sheets("Sheet1").cells(RowIndexDelta+1,1).value=<What you need for this test>

        Delta=Delta+1
    end if

    RowIndex=RowIndex+Delta+1

Loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to VBA so having your concepts have really helped.  I am still working through some minor details.  I will most likely have a question or two as I work at fine tuning it. Plus, I will be able to provide the code I am working with, as that maybe helpful.

Comment: I would use this code to write down your value:
`Sheets("WeeklyReport").range(Cells(RowIndex + 1, 3),Cells(RowIndex+1,12)).value=sheets("WeeklyReport").range(Cells(RowIndex,1),Cells(RowIndex,12))`

FillDown does somehting else and I don't think it is what you want

Comment: I added .Value to the end of your code and it worked great! Thanks.  I'm working to expand this out to the next column, but ran into one problem.  I have updated my original post.  Any help again is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong from your update.  Can you be more explicit?

Comment: I have updated to be more explicit.  Hopefully that will help.